# Floating Elements Span Adding Space

Tags: css, border, padding, css-float

I have something like the following code:

```
<div style="border:2px black solid;overflow:hidden;">
    <span style="float:right;">
        <img src="sprintlogo.png" alt="Test Image 1" />
    </span>
    <img src="sprintlogo.png" alt="Test Image 2" style="float:left;" />
    <p>Test Text</p>
</div>
```

For some reason, the bottom border around the `<div>` is not flush with the images, etc. For example, we get things like this:

[image: Example]

It's not an issue with the images or anything (i.e. there is no whitespace in the image file).

By adding `background-color:blue;` to the `<span>`'s `style` attribute, we can see that the span seems to be taking up extra space.

[image: Example 2]

I tried messing with the span's margin and padding to no avail. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) please make an example

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/dgzkU/](http://jsfiddle.net/dgzkU/) sorry, somehow I missed the large code chunk...

Comment: Can't you just drop that span since it doesn't do anything? http://jsfiddle.net/dgzkU/5/

Comment: I guess the span seems pointless in the sample code, but my code needs it (it's much more complex).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very strange indeed.

I found that by removing the span and simply floating the image right it removes the extraspace. Indicating the issue was in the span.

Then I looked at firebug and found that the extra space was rendered height.

Apparently the space is being creating by a stray character (which is odd because the character is still there if you remove whitespace...), as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pXXSQ/1/) where I turn font-size to 0 and the space goes away.

### Edit

Yeah the issue is most definitely that the image is being positioned assuming there is text and aligning it with the imagarinary text (`veritcal-align:baseline;`) another fix would be to align the image with the bottom of this text [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pXXSQ/3/).

Comment: Indeed, it is strange. Was it a whitespace character?

Comment: The `font-size:0px;` worked, but the `vertical-align:baseline;` did not (at least for me). Thanks. +1

Comment: Baseline is working here on ff8.0.1, and it wasn't a whitespace character which is whats messing with my head...

Comment: I was checking in Chrome. Do you know what character it was?